# Log internal IP address in apache2

Tags: apache-http-server, logging

I have a pretty standard apache2 installation (2.4.7) with name based vhosts. I would like to log in the `access.log` file private IP address of users who visit this website from NATed hosts.

In other words, besides logging his routable IP address (his gateway's IP), I'd like to also log his internal IP (e.g. 192.168.1.1) along the way.

I remember this being possible fairly easily back in the day (pre 2.0 days)

I tried `X-Forwarded-For`, but it seems to contain the same value as regular client IP.

I've also found [this bit](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_remoteip.html#processing), which might play a role:

> All internal addresses 10/8, 172.16/12, 192.168/16, 169.254/16 and 127/8 blocks (and IPv6 addresses outside of the public 2000::/3 block) are only evaluated by mod_remoteip when RemoteIPInternalProxy internal (intranet) proxies are registered.

How can I make it work? What mods and what log format string should I use?

Comment: 1. Why do you need this information? 2. You can't get this from the HTTP request. You can usually get there original IP from proxied requests, but NAT is not a proxy.

Comment: 1. Wrong question. I simply want to log this info. 2. Are you sure apache2 cannot get it? I remember years ago inspecting request headers and seeing IP addresses listed as a pair with a coma: external, internal ip, like this: `8.8.8.8,192.168.1.1`.

Comment: 1. No, very relevant question. No webserver should care about an IP they can't access. 2. I'm sure, it's data that is not included in the HTTP request. What your describing sounds like the X-Forwarded-For header, but that only applies to proxies.

Comment: I guess I might have mixed proxy with NAT. That would make sense. Thanks.